# Firebase Realtime Database: How to get the unique key after push().set()?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

In my flutter code, below is what I am doing to save data to Firebase Real-TIME Database

```
final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('chat_room');

void _sendMessage({String messageText, String imageUrl}) async{
    await reference.push().set({
      'text': messageText,
      'imageUrl': imageUrl,
    });

  }
```

This generates the following result in database

[image]

I need to retrieve the unique key generated as soon as I have submitted the data, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`push()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/push.html) method returns a [`DatabaseReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference-class.html), so you can do as follows:

```
final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('chat_room');

void _sendMessage({String messageText, String imageUrl}) async {
    DatabaseReference newRef = reference.push();
    String newKey = newRef.key;
    await newRef.set({
      'text': messageText,
      'imageUrl': imageUrl,
    });

  }
```

Note that you immediately get the new `DatabaseReference` when calling the `push()` method: no need to wait for the call to the asynchronous `set()` method to complete.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give me a hand on this one a well please? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876013/firebase-real-time-database-triggers-null-error-if-there-is-no-matching-data

Answer (score 2):

You can get that id with a different approach. First, you can get the next id, and push the item into it. It will look like this:

```
final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('chat_room');

void _sendMessage({String messageText, String imageUrl}) async{

    String newkey = reference.push().key; // That is your unique key!

   await reference.child(newkey).set({
      'text': messageText,
      'imageUrl': imageUrl,
    });
  }
```